# How to plot multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have data which is like this

```
 Date,     VID, C1,  C2, C3
 2/1/2014, V01, ON,  OFF, OFF 
 2/2/2014, V01, ON,  OFF, OFF 
 2/3/2014, V01, ON,  OFF, OFF 
 2/4/2014, V01, ON,  OFF, OFF 
 2/1/2014, V02, OFF, ON,  OFF 
 2/3/2014, V02, OFF, OFF, ON 
 2/4/2014, V02, ON,  ON,  OFF 
 2/5/2014, V02, ON,  OFF, ON
```

There are many VID's And C1, C2,C3 are Categorical.
Here is how I plot this & this is very time consuming so wanted to know if i can plot all time series for one VID ib one graph and how do that for all VID's ?

```
library(sqldf)
library(zoo)

#I execute this code for each variable and get separate plot
#I would like to plot all C1,C2,C3 for each vehicle in single plot
#and plot for each vehicle 
vehicle_V01 = sqldf("select * from df where Vehicle='V01'")
vehicle_V01$C1_numeric = as.numeric(vehicle_V01$C1)
vehicle_V01$C2_numeric = as.numeric(vehicle_V01$C2)
vehicle_V01$C3_numeric = as.numeric(vehicle_V01$C3)
ts = zoo(vehicle_V01$C1_numeric ,vehicle_V01$Date)
plot(ts)
```

This is very time costuming, any idea how to do it efficiently?

Comment: If the Cs are just ON and OFF, it's not really a time series, is it? The only numeric values they could take would be 1 and 2.

Comment: You can have time series with binary data.  They can't be analyzed using traditional time series analysis techniques alone, but it is a valid type of time series.  See here for an abstract on the issue:

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-306-48102-2_9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `ggplot2` and `reshape2` to plot and reshape the data.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df=melt(df,id.vars=c('Date','VID'))
df$value=as.numeric(vehicle$value)#ON = 2, OFF = 1

ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=value))+geom_line()+facet_grid('variable+VID~.')
```

The Date value was changed on the last 3 lines to be one less, but the output graphic looks like what you see below.  Is this what you're looking for?  (Also, I didn't use the date values you used, but you can use them when you run the code or just change the axis labels to them).

[image]

Comment: THANKS!!, yes this is what I wanted, except I want to group all plots for Vehicle (V01) together then V02 and so on, instead of by C(n). Any idea how that can be done?

Comment: How did you want to treat the C(n)?  Since there are three different variables (in your case), you'd need to do them one at a time (by subsetting the data (e.g., `df1=df[,df$variable=='C1']`) if you didn't want to group by them.  

You could also do `ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=value,group=variable))+geom_line()+facet_grid('VID~.')`, but then you won't be able to distinguish different values the way the graphics look.  You could add a `color=variable` or `linetype=variable`, but there will still be overlap issues if you do that.